# Images not showing in ipad simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ios-simulator

I've put items into the folder of this filepath: 
**/Users/ollie/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/DCIM/100Apple/** because I'm testing a `UIImagePickerController` and then renamed it to IMG_0002.png as there was already an mp4 file in there though ran the app and opened the view it didn't show and also when I went into the pictures app the mp4 was there though the image wasn't.

I haven't got a clue why this is not working though I suspect it must happen quite a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For media to show up it needs to be in the index that the device keeps in an internal CoreData DB. Add items to the simulators media by simple dragging the image onto simulator.

Then Mobile Safari opens showing the image. From there you can save the photo to the pictures. Then it will show up in the image picker.